# Why is Make ignoring an explicit pattern rule?

Tags: makefile, ibm-midrange

I'm using GNU Make 4.0 to compile code on an IBM i system.  Make is inexplicably choosing the wrong rule to build one type of object.

On this platform, program objects are built from modules, which are compiled from source code.  There is also a convenience shortcut command that will create a program directly from a single piece of source code by creating a temporary module from the source code and then building a program from that.  The problem I'm running into is that Make is using the shortcut command (`crtbndrpg`) instead of the two-step version (`crtrpgmod` + `crtpgm`), even though the target rule specifies that the program should be built from a module and not the shortcut.

There are two makefiles: a generic one that describes how to create IBM i objects, and a project-specific one that describes object dependencies for all items in this project and `include`s the generic one.  My generic makefile looks like this (edited for simplicity):

```
# `IBMiMake`, a generic makefile that describes how to create IBM i objects.

OBJPATH := $(CURDIR)
override OBJPATH := $(shell echo "$(OBJPATH)" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')

%.MODULE: %.RPGLE
    $(eval crtcmd := crtrpgmod module($(OBJLIB)/$*) srcstmf('$<') $(CRTRPGMODFLAGS))
    @system "$(crtcmd)" > $(LOGPATH)/$(notdir $<).log

%.PGM: %.RPGLE
    $(eval crtcmd := crtbndrpg pgm($(OBJLIB)/$*) srcstmf('$<') $(CRTBNDRPGFLAGS))
    system "$(crtcmd)" >$(LOGPATH)/$(notdir $<).log 2>&1

%.PGM:
    $(eval crtcmd := crtpgm pgm($(OBJLIB)/$*) module($(basename $(filter %.MODULE,$(notdir $^)))) $(CRTPGMFLAGS))
    system "$(crtcmd)" >$(LOGPATH)/$@.log 2>&1
```

The project-specific makefile looks like this (also edited for simplicity):

```
# `xpmake`, to create objects in this project.
ROOTDIR := $(shell dirname $(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
IBMIMAKE := $(ROOTDIR)/../SDE/IBMiMake
include $(IBMIMAKE)

# AB2001.B.MODULE -- CRTRPGMOD
AB2001.B.MODULE: AB2001.B.RPGLE

# AB2001.B.PGM -- CRTPGM
AB2001.B.PGM: AB2001.B.MODULE
```

To build the object in question:

```
bash-4.2$ make AB2001.B.PGM OBJPATH:='/qsys.lib/xp33make.lib' -f xp33make/xpmake -d --no-builtin-rules
```

What should happen: It should first create the module using the `crtrpgmod` command, which it does.  It should then create the program using the `crtpgm` command.  Instead of creating the program via `crtpgm`, however, it for some reason tries to use the `crtbndrpg` command to directly build the program from source code.  The only thing I can think of is that perhaps Make is seeing AB2001.B.MODULE as an intermediate file and opting to bypass the `crtrpgmod` step.  Could this be true?  How do I get make to follow my rules and not try to overthink things?

Here is the output:

```
GNU Make 4.0
Built for powerpc-ibm-aix5.3.0.0
Copyright (C) 1988-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile 'xp33make/xpmake'...
Reading makefile '/home/SMEEP/Source/xp33make/../SDE/IBMiMake' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file '/home/SMEEP/Source/xp33make/../SDE/IBMiMake'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for '/home/SMEEP/Source/xp33make/../SDE/IBMiMake'.
  No implicit rule found for '/home/SMEEP/Source/xp33make/../SDE/IBMiMake'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file '/home/SMEEP/Source/xp33make/../SDE/IBMiMake'.
 No need to remake target '/home/SMEEP/Source/xp33make/../SDE/IBMiMake'.
 Considering target file 'xp33make/xpmake'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for 'xp33make/xpmake'.
  No implicit rule found for 'xp33make/xpmake'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file 'xp33make/xpmake'.
 No need to remake target 'xp33make/xpmake'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file 'AB2001.B.PGM'.
 File 'AB2001.B.PGM' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for 'AB2001.B.PGM'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem 'AB2001.B'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite 'AB2001.B.CLLE'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem 'AB2001.B'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite 'AB2001.B.RPGLE'.
 Found an implicit rule for 'AB2001.B.PGM'.
  Considering target file 'AB2001.B.RPGLE'.
   Looking for an implicit rule for 'AB2001.B.RPGLE'.
   No implicit rule found for 'AB2001.B.RPGLE'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'AB2001.B.RPGLE'.
  No need to remake target 'AB2001.B.RPGLE'; using VPATH name '/home/SMEEP/Source/xp33make/AB2001.B.RPGLE'.
  Considering target file 'AB2001.B.MODULE'.
   Looking for an implicit rule for 'AB2001.B.MODULE'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'AB2001.B'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'AB2001.B.C'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'AB2001.B'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'AB2001.B.CLLE'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'AB2001.B'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'AB2001.B.RPGLE'.
   Found prerequisite 'AB2001.B.RPGLE' as VPATH '/home/SMEEP/Source/xp33make/AB2001.B.RPGLE'
   Found an implicit rule for 'AB2001.B.MODULE'.
    Pruning file '/home/SMEEP/Source/xp33make/AB2001.B.RPGLE'.
    Pruning file '/home/SMEEP/Source/xp33make/AB2001.B.RPGLE'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'AB2001.B.MODULE'.
   Prerequisite '/home/SMEEP/Source/xp33make/AB2001.B.RPGLE' is older than target 'AB2001.B.MODULE'.
   Prerequisite '/home/SMEEP/Source/xp33make/AB2001.B.RPGLE' is older than target 'AB2001.B.MODULE'.
  No need to remake target 'AB2001.B.MODULE'; using VPATH name '/QSYS.LIB/XP33MAKE.LIB/AB2001.B.MODULE'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'AB2001.B.PGM'.
Must remake target 'AB2001.B.PGM'.
system "crtbndrpg pgm(XP33MAKE/AB2001.B) srcstmf('/home/SMEEP/Source/xp33make/AB2001.B.RPGLE')" >/home/SMEEP/Source/xp33make/Logs/2016-11-14_11.42.55-Mon/AB2001.B.RPGLE.log 2>&1
Putting child 30016df0 (AB2001.B.PGM) PID 1155363 on the chain.
Live child 30016df0 (AB2001.B.PGM) PID 1155363 
Reaping losing child 30016df0 PID 1155363 
/home/SMEEP/Source/xp33make/../SDE/IBMiMake:476: recipe for target 'AB2001.B.PGM' failed
Removing child 30016df0 PID 1155363 from chain.
```

Comment: Why specify a **crtbndrpg** rule at all? All ILE RPG programs can be created using crtrpgmod+crtpgm, even ones that **may** be created using crtbndrpg.

Comment: You're right, and that's the direction I ended up going.

Answer (score 3):

Your example is still difficult to read: creating a minimal example is usually best (that is, construct an example that uses `touch` etc. to create files, and doesn't depend on your environment).

Also, the use of `$(eval ...)` inside the recipe to create a make variable assignment is a bit confusing.  Don't think that just because you do this in the recipe there's some kind of scoping involved: those variables are still globally assigned.

In any event, the problem is that you have two ways to build a target that matches `%.PGM`:

```
%.PGM: %.RPGLE
%.PGM:
```

You apparently want to use the second one, but if the stem of a matching pattern rule is has equal length (here both have the same stem, `.PGM`) then `make` will always choose the first pattern that you define so it will always choose the first one if it can.

So, it will always use `crtbndrpg` to build that target, as long as `make` can figure out how to build `%.RPGLE`, so that pattern rule will match.

Comment: Thank you. You're right, it's far too complicated.  I struggled with creating a generic example, but in the future I'll make sure I succeed.  Given the rules `%.c: %.b`, `%.b: %.a`, and `%.c: %.a`, is there any possible way to control which rule will take effect for a definition like `xyz.c: xyz.b` or `xyz.c: xyz.a`?  We have some items that are supposed to be created with the shortcut `%.c: %.a` rule, but others that should use the two steps of `%.c: %.a` plus `%.c: %.b`.  How can we tell Make which to use?

Comment: Try adding another rule without recipe in xpmake in order to cancel the unwanted rule from IBMiMake, like `%.PGM: %.RPGLE`.

Comment: If you never want to use one of the patterns in a given makefile, then you can delete that as jaeheung says.  If you need all the patterns in the same makefile for different things, then you can't leave it up to make.  It can't just intuit what you want to do; it will always use the same algorithm to search for rules for each target.  In this case you'll have to create an explicit rule, maybe a static pattern rule, for the targets which don't use the "standard" behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if they're omitted in the simplifying process, but your explicit rules lack their recipes.
Pattern rules with no recipe mean canceling any existing implicit rules.
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html

Comment: It would only cancel the pattern rule if the pattern rule had no recipe.  Here your pattern rules have recipes.  The no-recipe rules just define extra prerequisites.  Since there's no recipe, there's no explicit rule and make will search the pattern rules to find a recipe.